# Non-blocking sockets and send()

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winapi, network-programming

Based on my underestimating of non-blocking sockets, when I want to `send()` data, if the send buffer is full, `send()` will return an error. But my question is the following:

If the send buffer has room for 5 bytes, and I tried to send 15 bytes, will the entire 15 bytes not be send, or will 5 bytes be send, and it's my responsibility to see how much data were actually sent, and re-send the remaining bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be told by `send` how many bytes where sucessfully sent and it's totally your responsibilty to handle anything not sent.  But there are plenty of libraries that will help you in this.